# Apply affine transformations to images in TensorFlow2

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, affinetransform

I am trying to apply affine transformations, represented as a tensor (batch_size, 3, 3), to a tensor containing a batch of images (batch_size, channels, height, width) in TensorFlow 2.

A general transformation can be applied to the tensor by using `tfa.image.transform` (https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/transform), but this takes projective transformations as input rather than affine transformations. A projective transform is an 8 dimensional vector representing the transformations instead of a  3 X 3 matrix. In Tensorflow 1 this was easy to solve by using `tf.contrib.image.matrices_to_flat_transforms` to convert the affine transformation to projective ones. This functionality is however no longer available in Tensorflow 2, and as far as I can see there is no new functionality in tfa that replaces this.

So my question is: If I have a tensor of affine transformation and a tensor containing a batch of images, how can I apply the transformation to the images in TensorFlow 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the necessary functionality does still exist in TensorFlow 2, but the documentation on the website (https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/) seems incomplete. The function is available as: `tensorflow_addons.image.transform_ops.matrices_to_flat_transforms`